# bigquery storage api got hang at create read session

Tags: python-3.x, google-bigquery, python-bigquery

I can use the [BigQuery Storage API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/storage/) to read the sample public dataset.  But when I created my own dataset, it got hand at create read session: `client.create_read_session`.  The problem still persists even I granted the public read access to the dataset.

The problem still persists even I granted the public read access to the dataset.

Comment: Be more specific, show the code you tried, the error you got etc. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: As @cccnrc mentioned, please add more information to your answer so we can help you.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with `client.create_read_session` like below

**From public dataset(project_id: bigquery-public-data):**

- Fine

**From my private dataset 'A':**

- Error(Hang) with no retry option
- Error(503:Service Unavailable) with retry=None

**From my private dataset 'B':**

- Fine again

hmm...

And I carefully started looking at each schema of A/B, 
and realized that EU/US region was OK but Seoul, S.Korea(asia-northeast3) might not be supported for now.

I guess that your region might not be supported just like my situation.